# How to keep two rows adjacent in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have a Tablix in my .rdlc file. [image: As Given below]

I open my report file in pdf format. But some times 'OtherInfoLabel' comes to the bottom of a page and the data(OtherInfo) goes to the next page.

is there any way to keep both label and Text together?

Comment: I believe tablix has the option to add a page break before it.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to check the size of the tablix and decide if to break or not.

What you can do is:

- On the General tab, under Page break options, select one of the
  following options: Add a page break before.
- Select this option when
  you want to add a page break before the table. Add a page break
  after.
- Select this option when you want to add a page break after the
  table.
- Fit table on one page if possible. Select this option when you
  want the data to stay on one page.

Refer: [Tablix page break](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156434%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Take one rectangle first and then place both label and text inside that rectangle. So it ensures that both things come in same line.